# What is the IID in Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "...") and why do I need it

Tags: qt, qt5

I am currently working on QT Plugins and came across the macro Q_PLUGIN_METADATA. Here you have to define an IDD. Many examples use "QQmlEngineExtensionInterface_iid" to declare the IID but this gives me a "Parse Error at "IID""-exception for the following line which can be often found in examples:

```
Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID QQmlEngineExtensionInterface_iid);
```

If I define any string like "com.my.module" I don´t get this exception. Nevertheless I think i am suffering a lack of knowledge about the real use of this Macro and the documentation gives not enoug information for me on that. I need to understand what this IID actually does and where I will need it later in the plugin usage.